# How can I order my JSON data by date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a website that displays artwork, the artwork is stored on a Firebase Realtime Database. But I would like for it to be formatted and ordered in date.

I've tried to use the array.sort method but my data is not in an array.

```
<artwork_id>{
    artworkCompletionDate: "12-12-1212",
    artworkDescription: {
        "shortDesc": "",
        "longDesc": ""
    },
    artworkName: "",
    //etc...

},
<artwork_id_2>{...}
```

Comment: Please share sample json object so I can provide suggestion

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data

Comment: First, the question is incomplete - where's the code you're using to read Firebase ordered by `artworkCompletionDate`. Second, that's not how to properly store a date. Storing it as a string is fine but for sorting, it will need to be yyyy-MM-dd formatted. Lastly, it's not clear why you need an array - each piece of artwork will be stored in it's own child node so an array is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this JSON? In your example it looks like a regular JS object. Anyway, when you have a JS object that contains many objects, you can convert it to an array of the objects with the following code:

```
// Assume that the JSON data is stored in a variable called `artworkData`

// Convert the JSON data into an array of objects
const artworkArray = Object.keys(artworkData).map((id) => {
  return {
    id: id,
    completionDate: new Date(artworkData[id].artworkCompletionDate),
    description: artworkData[id].artworkDescription,
    name: artworkData[id].artworkName
  };
});
```

You can then sort it using the sort() method. But note that the sort method sorts alphabetically, and it will not sort numbers correctly.
To sort numbers using the sort method, you can use the following trick
`artworkArray.sort((a, b) => a.completionDate - b.completionDate);`

For more information on using the sort method to sort by numbers, see [JavaScript Array sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp) and [JavaScript Sorting Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) in w3schools.

Comment: OP is talking about getting data from a database. The proper time to sort the data is *when the database is being queried*, not in application code. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data. Additionally, those are not valid ISO 8601 date strings, feeding them to the date constructor will have unpredictable results.